# How to send data from one com port to the other?

Tags: android, usb, port, usb-otg

I am working on an application where I need to connect my android mobile to a sensor (USB-OTG) & computer (for debugging) as well. But I can connect to only one of them at a time, which eats all of my time.

Is there a way to connect the USB sensor to my computer's USB port and mobile to the other USB port and fetch sensors data through computer to my android  application?

In other words, is there a way to send the data coming in from one USB port to an android device connected to another USB port?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you specify a programming language and a particular problem you experience regarding the data transfer from/to the USB devices, perhaps someone might be able to write more comprehensive answer.